# Tomcat7 ignoring JAVA_HOME

Tags: debian, tomcat, java

I have been trying to start tomcat7 server without success. I am using the Raspbian distro in a RaspberryPI.

When I try to start tomcat:

```
$ sudo service tomcat7 start
[FAIL] no JDK found - please set JAVA_HOME ... failed!
```

However `$ echo $JAVA_HOME` yields `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt`. Which I believe is the right path since:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java):
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
```

Thanks

Comment: There is a difference between JDK and JRE.... but tomcat shouldn't need a JDK, so I imagine you need to set it in /etc/defaults/ somewhere? If you run the init script with `bash -x /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start` then you might get a clue as to where its sourcing its environment. Try also `JAVA_HOME=...path/to/jre/ /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start`

Comment: @CameronKerr what should I look for when I run the script with `bash -x`?

Comment: Look for files that are consulted, and expecially anywhere that sets or tests JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed editing the `JAVA_HOME` within the `/etc/default/tomcat7` as this post [suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/154967/117231).